# unordered_map doesn't seem to return reference on [] operator

Tags: c++, unordered-map, c++14

I currently have a database class with a few unordered maps containing the databases variables. I have written functions for adding and deleting variables but now want a way to access and modify them easily.

My function is like this:

```
template<typename T>
T &get(const  std::string &name){
    if(typeid(T) == typeid(int))
        return this->ints[name];
    else if(typeid(T) == typeid(float))
        return this->floats[name];

     ... ect ...
}
```

And throws an error if an invalid type is given.

`ints` is type `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>`
and `floats` is defined likewise.

This, to me, looks correct. But when I try and run this I get the following error:

```
database.hpp:98: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'
```

Looks like the unordered map isn't returning a reference, what is the issue?

Comment: what is the declaration of `ints`? 
[subscript operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/) should return reference

Comment: unordered_map<string, int>
I know that it SHOULD, but it doesn't seem to in this situation (or at least the reference is converted to value).

Comment: When you instantiate your code with one type, you get return statements for all other types as well. I'm guessing that one of combinations you get for one of your instantiations causes the problem.

Comment: why not to do declare `unordered_map<string, T> store;` and then just return `store[name];`

Comment: better use find, as you don't want to create a new element..

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko I don't think you are reading the code correctly, I declare a few `unordered_map`s with different types for `T` in your example.

Comment: @Deduplicator I actually use the `[]` operator because I WANT it to create a new element if one doesn't exist.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode yes, and I am wondering what for :)

Comment: I need different stores for different variables so that there aren't name conflicts between types.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Not "one of the combinations".  ALL OF THEM.  Implicit conversion creates a temporary, which can't be returned by reference (nor would you want to, since its lifetime ends before the function returns).

Comment: @CoffeeandCode this is template function of non-template class? How will compiler deduce int type in the point of call. (what is in ...etc...)

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko: It isn't deduced, he probably calls it as `db.get<int>("Zipcode")`

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Please, tell us your compiler and platform :) I am really interested to reproduce your error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unline C# and Java generics, C++ templates can be specialized.  Testing types the way you are doing is strongly discouraged.

If you used specialization, you wouldn't be having this problem, as it's related to conversions as BartoszKP commented.

```
template<typename T>
T& get(const std::string &name);
```

and outside the class, but still inside the header:

```
template<>
int& ClassName::get<int>(const std::string &name) { return ints[name]; }

template<>
float& ClassName::get<float>(const std::string &name) { return floats[name]; }
```

Comment: Who exactly strongly discourages it? I prefer the code to be more generic, that way I can just add in another type check rather than another function definition with a different specialization.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: A compiler error message that you cannot work around isn't strong enough discouragement for you?  I've never seen *any* skilled C++ programmer use comparison of `typeinfo` structures.  I've seen specialization, and I've seen overloads disabled using `enable_if<same<>>`

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Chain of `if` statements alone is a code smell. Combining it with subsequent run-time type checking is not making it better, to be subtle.

Comment: I don't like the change to code, but a compiler error isn't something you can exactly work around. Bit rude to imply I wasn't a skilled C++ programmer though :L

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: The other thing about your code that makes me grimace is how much it looks like failure to use virtual dispatch.  (virtual functions aren't the solution here, of course)

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Even skilled programmers have bad days, I admit.  But you weren't demonstrating any skills when you failed to notice that the error for `int&` occurred on the line number for returning a float.  At least, I expect that's what happened.  We can't see what line of your source is `database.hpp:98`

Comment: Scratch that, the `ints` map was defined as `unordered_map<string, int64_t>` I couldn't see why your code wouldn't work. topkek.

Comment: Still unclear why the compile error happened. The code returning reference from the map should compile.

Comment: @Alexey: It does.  The error is caused by all the other return statements, which require conversion to the return type.  Did you read the comments under the question?  And deduplicator's answer?

Comment: @BenVoigt I read. The error then should be: `'return' : cannot convert from 'float' to 'int &'` (I have this error.)
The error pointed by author looks like temporary int rvalue is  returning, but I cannot catch how it could be from the code provided.

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko: Well, it CAN convert from `float` to `int`.  So the compiler error message isn't great, but it is accurate.  Different compilers and different versions might give a little different message.

Comment: @BenVoigt HOW can std::unordered_map convert float to int? Can you compile reproducible on some platform to prove?

Comment: @Alexey: `float f = 5.0f; int i = f;` compiles without any problems.  An implicit conversion exists, `std::unordered_map` is not involved in the error.

Comment: @BenVoigt This is different situation. Retuning float with return type int& would not compile - but OK, this is just what is happening here. You convinced me. Just different error message.

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko: Right.  `float&` can convert to `int`, but not to `int&`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am not sure with references.
  ` float f = 0.0;
    int i = 2;

    float& fr = i;  // both assignments are not compiled 
    int& ir   = f;  

non-const lvalue reference to type 'float' cannot bind to
      a value of unrelated type 'int'`  

(clang compiler)

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko: Yes, that's the error we're discussing.  What are you not sure about?  `float f = 5.0f; int i = f;` is fine, but `int& r = f;` is not.

Comment: @BenVoigt I meant, `float& f = i;` is not correct, too (for int i).
Reference requires exact match of type. So, map returns reference which cannot be converted to anything else, so still the error message is confusing.

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko: It's not exactly correct to say that a reference can't be converted to anything else.  It can undergo lvalue->rvalue conversion, and become a temporary variable of another type.  Also there is reference conversion, which allows adding cv-qualifiers.  For example: `int i; const int& r = i;` is fine, the `int&` converted to `const int&`.